# linux-imag-?-dbg and linux-headers package missing

Tags: raspbian, kernel, packages

I'd like to make use of systemtap on my 2016-02-09-raspbian/jessie system.
For that I need the kernel debug package and the kernel headers.

The kernel in use is:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# uname -r
4.1.17+
```

So I would expect these two to work on a Debian.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`-dbg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.1.17+-dbg
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.1.17+-dbg'


root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.1.17
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.1.17'
```

How do I find the matching debug kernel and headers on raspian?

Answer (score -3):

Try simply `apt-get install linux-headers linux-image`. To find specific versions, you can try `apt-show-versions <package>` if the package is already installed and `aptitude versions <package>` to check version of installation candidates.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no suitable candidates.

Comment: Does apt-get list any packages as being held back?